# awk or other bioinformatics tools to filter vcf

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to filter some lines in a vcf file, here is an example of lines:

```
1   10505   rs548419688 A   T   100 PASS    AC=1;AF=0.000199681;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=9632;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0.0008;E
UR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
1   10506   rs568405545 C   G   100 PASS    AC=1;AF=0.000199681;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=9676;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0.0008;E
UR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
1   10511   rs534229142 G   A   100 PASS    AC=1;AF=0.000199681;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=9869;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0014;AFR_AF=0;E
UR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
1   10539   rs537182016 C   A   100 PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=9203;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0014;AFR_AF=0;E
UR_AF=0.001;SAS_AF=0.001;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
1   10542   rs572818783 C   T   100 PASS    AC=1;AF=0.000199681;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=9007;EAS_AF=0.001;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EU
R_AF=0;SAS_AF=0;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
```

Say I want to extract lines with `AMR_AF` larger than 0.5, but couldn't figure out how to use Awk regular expressions to do such job. Tried `vcftools`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have let us know that you tried few things, please do add those efforts in your question too.

Comment: Also please be clear which occurance of string you want to check for? As it is not clear from your question.

Comment: The [tag:vcf] tag is for a calendar file format; surely this is something else?

Comment: Try `awk '{ split($0, x, /[\t;]AMR_AF=/) } x[2]>0.5' file.vcf`

Comment: There are no lines where `AMR_AF` is larger than 0.5 in your example.

Comment: @tripleee, true, I tested it with modified example for solution as no line is satisfying condition in OP's examples.

Comment: @tripleee thanks! this line of code works well, could you please briefly explain how it works? vcf is the format that show mutation information in bioinformatics. AMR_AF>0.5 is just a random thing popping out of my head, and yea there is no AMR_AF>0.5 in my lines of example. My apologies!

Comment: vcftools is replaced by bcftools, for almost all of VCF related problems this it the tool to use, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/AMR_AF=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|AMR_AF=[0-9]+/) && substr($0,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-7)>0.5'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `AMR_AF= digits.digits` OR `AMR_AF=digits` and whenever this regex gets matches on line then it sets `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variables. `&&`(AND condition) to check if sub-string value of `RSTART+7` to till `RLENGTH-7` value is greater than 0.5 then print that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the line on the field you choose and examine whether the numeric value of the element just after the split is larger than your threshold.

In some more detail, splitting the input `yes,foo=2,bar=0.23,baz=1` on `,bar=` will yield an array containing `yes,foo=2` and `0.23,baz=1`.  In Awk, if you compare the second element to `0.2`, it will simply convert as much as it can from the beginning of the value into a number and then perform a numeric comparison.

Thus

```
awk '{ split($0, x, /[\t;]AMR_AF=/) } x[2]>0.5' file.vcf
```

should do what you want. We split the line into `x` and examine the numeric value of `x[2]`.

The `[\t;]` in the regex allows for either a tab or a semicolon before the field's name; to be perfectly general, perhaps you should even use `(^|[\t;])` to also permit the match to happen at beginning of line.

If you want to parametrize this, maybe try

```
awk -v field="AMR_AF" -v thres=0.5 '{ split($0, x, "(^|[\t;])" field "=")) } x[2]>thres' file.vcf
```

Recall that Awk processes the script for each input line from top to bottom, where each script statement has the form

[ *condition* ] [ `{` *action* `}` ]

As the square brackets indicate, both parts are optional -- if *condition* is missing, the *action* is taken unconditionally; if *action*  is missing, it defaults to `{ print $0 }`. So our script will first unconditionally split the line, then conditionally print it if `x[2]` is larger than the threshold.

GNU Awk can split on a multi-character field separator, so you could use `-F '[\t;]AMR_AF='` too.

```
awk -F '[\t;]AMR_AF=' '$2>0.5' file.vcf
```

Comment: thank you very much for your speedy response! just a quick question: what if I want to extract the value between ```AMR_AF=``` and ```;AFR_AF```, and print the numeric value out, using regular expression?

Comment: That should be easy to figure out; `split` twice. You can also use the `match()` logic from RavinderSingh13's answer and calculate offsets from `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` to figure out the indices to extract the substring but I find it rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Using *bcftools*:

```
bcftools view -i 'INFO/AMR_AF > 0.5' myFile.vcf
```

See for more options from [bcftools manuals](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html#view).